# Fourier transform of a Schwartz space function and norm

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

The Schwartz space (of *rapidly decreasing* functions) is the set of all $C^{\infty}$ functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that 
$$
x^jf^{(k)}(x) \to 0
$$
for all integers $j,k\geq0$ as $x \to {\pm\infty}$.

Let $f$ be a rapidly decreasing function in Schwartz space and let $\mathcal{F}(f)$ its Fourier transform. If 
$$
\| f \|_2 = \| \mathcal{F}(f) \|_2 \quad,
$$ 
can we deduce that $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is a Schwartz function?

Answer (score 12):

You don't need their norms to be equal - this is a consequence of the normalization factor chosen for the Fourier transform, and is called the [Plancherel Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem)

To show that the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is Schwartz, it suffices to show the following:

- $k^\alpha\hat{f}(k)=i^{-\alpha}\mathcal{F}\left[f^{(\alpha)}\right]$
- $\frac{d^\alpha}{dk^\alpha}\hat{f}(k)=(-ik)^\alpha\hat{f}(k)$

Combine these two facts with the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) and you've got it.

Note: I'm using the following convention for the Fourier transform:

$$
\hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ikx}dx
$$

Comment: Why do those those two facts and the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma imply the result?

Comment: Since $f$ is Schwartz, all its derivatives will be $L^1$, so Riemann-Lebesgue gives that $\mathcal{F}[f^{(\alpha)}]$ goes to zero for any $\alpha$.  The two facts above relate this to decay of  $\hat{f}$ and its derivatives, which is needed to prove that $\hat{f}$ is Schwartz.